# Mapping action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my routs.rb I have the following lines

```
CyberTrackRails3::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|de|nl/ do
    resources :transfusion do
      get 'detail', :on => :collection
    end
  end
end
```

Next line

```
url_for( :controller => :transfusion, :action => :detail, 
            :id => bloodselection[:id]
```

gets mapped to **/nl/transfusion/detail?id=162106**

How do I map it to **/nl/transfusion/162106** so that controller understands it as id being 162106?

Comment: Think I just found it. Using :member instead of :collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you are setting the detail action on collection, to follow your url structure, it needs to be defined on member.

ie,

```
CyberTrackRails3::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|de|nl/ do
    resources :transfusion do
      get 'detail', :on => :member
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The Rails routing engine pluralizes collections by default, so if you want the defaults to work out of the box, you should use the plural, `transfusions`

Then instead of `url_for`, you could use `transfusion_path` to get `/nl/transfusions/12345`

If you insist on using the singular form in the URL, you can override the path segment as

```
resources :transfusions, path: "transfusion" do …
```

which would let you get `/nl/transfusion/12345` instead.

Comment: To make the defaults work, what should routes.rb look like? I would like to use transfusion_path for instance. Btw, detail isn't the only action, so it should be transfusion_detail_path.

Comment: It actually depends on what your controller class is named. If it is named `TransfusionController`, then using `resources :transfusion` should work, but if you have a model called `Transfusion`, rails expects the controller to be named `TransfusionsController` so it is a chain reaction